how to identify new failures within gitlabCI daily scheduled pipeline
Using GitlabCI, we've scheduled a bunch of tests to run daily.
When this test job is failing, we receive a (slack) notification in a dedicated channel.
Now I'd like to push it further: I want to notify to different channels depending of the presence of new failures.
Having the distinction done in gitlab-CI pipeline test result pages would be less satisfying but acceptable.
I've done my HomeWorks and found that Gitlab-CI do not have this possibility built in (contrary to say Jenkins).
So, I'm wondering what are my options to create such a feature: are there plugins, can we extend gitlab-CI ourselves for that?
For now on, our team is envisioning sending the results to an external tool (ie: our monitoring which is datadog) for it to do the heavy work, but I'd rather avoid having a multi layer stack if possible.
